# Drupal web forms that can be half-filled and remember my input when I come back

Tags: php, drupal, forms

Drupal's webform module is awesome for building forms, but since my form is **very long**, I'd like my users to be able to:

1. Fill in some data,
2. Save them (without submitting the form)
3. Do something else and finally
4. Come back after some time to fill in the rest of the data and submit.

Is there a way to do this?

I suppose this is a common issue since long forms are hard to fill-in all at once.

Comment: how long do you need to keep the field data before submitting it? does the user keep the page open or does the page/site/browser close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, partial save has been part of webform module for awhile, but there're some issues with it. Check [this](http://drupal.org/node/226907).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a custom module, but I don't know of any ready made solution.

Also, I don't think this is a common issue, I have never seen forms that on a webpage where you needed so much time to fill it in, that you needed to save the work, before being able to complete it.

You should seriously review the usability of such forms, if they are so time consuming to complete, are all the fields really needed, could this be done in an alternate and better way?